# are downloaded update files ecrypted or not?

Tags: encryption

Yesterday needed to use the command " sudo apt update" while installing vpn when  i noticed that the address of some ubuntu servers did not begin with https but instead http. so i began wondering, does it mean that the downloaded files are not encrypted?

Comment: They are all digitally signed, and if the checksum does not match, Ubuntu is supposed to not install them.

Comment: aha. i did not know that.

Comment: thanks  Archisman Panigrah